# HTML Table Wrap Column

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table where users input data into columns. Each time the user enters data a new column is created. After a while they have a TON of columns and I need them to wrap.

I know how to wrap the text inside the columns, but I need the entire column to wrap below the first column and so on.

Comment: You probably don't want to be using a table for this. Can you post the relevant parts of your code so we can help you better?

Comment: This is a link to a test I created. As you'll see I gather data from other areas to populate the table. I just need to be able to wrap the columns if more data is entered. http://www.freefilehosting.net/test_28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use tables for this.
You should use divs with "float: left" CSS style.

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/3MEJ5/

Comment: Float is never a solution nor should be considered as one. It adds complexity for something that can easily be achieved with `inline-block`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using table columns, try having each input data be a table on its own, wrapped inside a `<div class="datainput">`, using the following CSS:

```
.datainput {display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;}
```

Now, instead of adding a new column, duplicate the container. This will place it next to the existing ones, and wrap if/when needed.

Should it fail to wrap, apply this CSS to the element containing all these containers:

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Answer (score 1):

it is actually not simple. The table/row/column structure is quite rigid. To achieve what you describe, you have to create each cell as a single-celled table in a giant outer cell. Then they will wrap. But then, they may not align well.

Answer (score -1):

A good solution for this now is to use CSS3 Columns.

You can set the CSS properties on the container and the children will flow down and across.

You have the options:

```
div {
  /* Make columns with a min width of 100px, create multiple columns as space permits */
  column-width: 100px;
  column-count: 3; /* Divide the text in a <div> element into three columns */
  column-gap: 40px;  /* Specify a 40 pixels gap between the columns */
  /* Specify the width, style, and color of the rule between columns */
  column-rule: 4px double #ff00ff;
}
```

For more details see: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_columns.asp

For browser support see: https://caniuse.com/#search=css3%20columns