# adjust columns of a table in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to have a table, such that if the width of the page decreases the columns of the table should be displayed one below the other.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet or maybe a link to jsFiddle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901904/html-table-wrap-column

Comment: No you cannot do this to a table column. Please use DIVs instead so they wrap to meet viewport width.

Comment: bbh look at my awnser it is possible

Comment: Just use bootstrap: getbootstrap.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS display properties to alter the way the table behaves. In order to make the table cells sit one on top of the other, you need to create a media query which will set the table and each cell to be  `display: block` at the break point that best suits your needs.

In the example below the table cells will wrap when the screen width shrinks to 500px.

## Example

```css
@media (max-width: 500px) {

    table {
        display: block;
        border: solid 1px #f00;
    }
    table td {
        display: block;
        border: solid 1px #f00;
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

## Explanation

By default a `table` tag uses `display: table` and a table cell uses `display: table-cell`. By changing these properties we can alter the way the table is displayed.

For more information on **display** properties see this article:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

For more information on **media queries** see the following article:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: @lain To be honest: I'm not. My answer is based on the limited amount of information provided in the question which makes no mention of a table header.

Comment: Indeed, the question neither includes nor excludes headers. Yet my question was more based on curiosity :)

Comment: @lain I thought it was better to point him/her in the right direction regarding the manipulation of display properties rather than provide a specific example that might not fit his needs. At least armed with the basic knowledge he/she could find a solution themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Alright if i understand correctly you want something like this:
http://codepen.io/geoffyuen/pen/FCBEg

This Solution wil make your table responsive so it can do what you are trying to do(at leat i think i know what youre trying to do)

Just some example html code

```
<h1>RWD List to Table</h1>
<table class="rwd-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Movie Title</th>
    <th>Genre</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Gross</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">Star Wars</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">Adventure, Sci-fi</td>
    <td data-th="Year">1977</td>
    <td data-th="Gross">$460,935,665</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">Howard The Duck</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">"Comedy"</td>
    <td data-th="Year">1986</td>
    <td data-th="Gross">$16,295,774</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">American Graffiti</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">Comedy, Drama</td>
    <td data-th="Year">1973</td>
    <td data-th="Gross">$115,000,000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then we have our CSS

```
@import "compass/css3";

// More practical CSS...
// using mobile first method (IE8,7 requires respond.js polyfill https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)

$breakpoint-alpha: 480px; // adjust to your needs

.rwd-table {
  margin: 1em 0;
  min-width: 300px; // adjust to your needs

  tr {
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  }

  th {
    display: none; // for accessibility, use a visually hidden method here instead! Thanks, reddit!   
  }

  td {
    display: block; 

    &:first-child {
      padding-top: .5em;
    }
    &:last-child {
      padding-bottom: .5em;
    }

    &:before {
      content: attr(data-th)": "; // who knew you could do this? The internet, that's who.
      font-weight: bold;

      // optional stuff to make it look nicer
      width: 6.5em; // magic number :( adjust according to your own content
      display: inline-block;
      // end options

      @media (min-width: $breakpoint-alpha) {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  }

  th, td {
    text-align: left;

    @media (min-width: $breakpoint-alpha) {
      display: table-cell;
      padding: .25em .5em;

      &:first-child {
        padding-left: 0;
      }

      &:last-child {
        padding-right: 0;
      }
    }

  }


}


// presentational styling

@import 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700';

body {
  padding: 0 2em;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  color: #444;
  background: #eee;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: #34495E;
}

.rwd-table {
  background: #34495E;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: .4em;
  overflow: hidden;
  tr {
    border-color: lighten(#34495E, 10%);
  }
  th, td {
    margin: .5em 1em;
    @media (min-width: $breakpoint-alpha) { 
      padding: 1em !important; 
    }
  }
  th, td:before {
    color: #dd5;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you